# How to convert datatable to dictionary in ASP.NET/C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

The `DataTable` below:

```
ClassID  ClassName  StudentID  StudentName
    1        A          1000      student666
    2        B          1100      student111
    5        C          1500      student777
    1        A          1200      student222
    2        B          1080      student999
```

The dictionary key  is composed of "ClassID ,ClassName " and value is composed of "StudentID,StudentName" .

```
Dictionary<string, string> d = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
{
    string key=dr["ClassID"].ToString() + dr["ClassName"].ToString();
    if (!d.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        //Do something();......
    }
    else
    {
        //Do something();......
    }
}
foreach (var s in d.Keys)
{
    Response.Write(s+"|+"+d[s]+"<br>");
}
```

Is there a faster way?

assume that key is '1,A' ,Value should be ' 1000,student666' and '1200,student222'

Comment: Since this is quite simple, I'm gonna ask: what did you try ?

Comment: `dictionary key is composed of "ClassID ,ClassName " and value is composed of "StudentID,StudentName"` ... What?

Comment: Is there a faster way to achieve?

Comment: @zespri like user2540812's answer

Comment: @SimonBelanger simple?Please post your answer!Thanks

Comment: Could you please post your code, that you are trying to improve (make faster, etc).

Comment: As @SimonBelanger pointed out in my answer, the key you specify is not unique. For example, what should be returned as the value corresponding to key 1,A?  There are two rows.

Comment: assume that key is '1,A' ,Value should be ' 1000,student666' and     '1200,student222'

Comment: That's two values... do you want each element to be a list instead?

Comment: @pilotcam Yes !you are right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here goes then. Using Linq, you can group them then perform string concatenation if you want.

```
// Start by grouping
var groups = table.AsEnumerable()
        .Select(r => new {
                      ClassID = r.Field<int>("ClassID"),
                      ClassName = r.Field<string>("ClassName"),
                      StudentID = r.Field<int>("StudentID"),
                      StudentName = r.Field<string>("StudentName")
                  }).GroupBy(e => new { e.ClassID, e.ClassName });

// Then create the strings. The groups will be an IGrouping<TGroup, T> of anonymous objects but
// intellisense will help you with that.
foreach(var line in groups.Select(g => String.Format("{0},{1}|+{2}<br/>", 
                                       g.Key.ClassID, 
                                       g.Key.ClassName,
                                       String.Join(" and ", g.Select(e => String.Format("{0},{1}", e.StudentID, e.StudentName))))))
{
    Response.Write(line);
}
```

Comment: Good example of why I like Linq (+1)

Comment: I typed it in the answer box (no access to my development computer at the moment). There might be some typos but that's the gist of it.

Comment: 'list = (from st in datatable.AsEnumerable()
                            select new CcompositeClass
                            {
                                ClassID = st.Field<string>("ClassID"),
                                ClassName = st.Field<string>("ClassName"),'

Comment: @SimonBelanger: Note that `DataTable.Rows` does not implement IEnumerable, so above as written won't work. I've edited your code to fix this. `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` assembly has to be referenced for this to work.

Comment: Also note that this is less useful in a common scenario where you need to pass data outside of the method and format and output them elsewhere, may be in more than one place. This is because the `groups` variable ends up being of anonymous type. You still can pass it outside if you declare the type to be *dynamic* but then you loose strong typing and get little benefit. It probably worth creating a new type here that can be passed around.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> d = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
            {
                string key=dr["ClassID"].ToString() + "-" + dr["ClassName"].ToString();
                string value=dr["StudentID"].ToString() + "-" + dr["StudentName"].ToString();
                if (!d.ContainsKey(key))
                {
                    d.Add(key, value);
                }

            }
```

***Reference***
[**Dictionary.Add Method**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7z0zy8k.aspx)

OR ELSE Try ***Onkelborg***'s Answer

[How to use compound key for dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976238/how-to-use-compound-key-for-dictionary)

Comment: Same problem  as pilotcam's original answer. This silently kill any (StudentId, StudentName) past the first one.

Answer (score 0):

The tricky thing here is the composite key  (ClassID, ClassName).  Once you identify that, it's easy to search this site for the solution.

I'd recommend using tuples as pointed out here: [Composite Key Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877660/composite-key-dictionary)

Comment: Wouldn't work, the composite key in his example is not unique.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a string value of ClassID|ClassName as key. For example, use string value "1|A" for key for the first row, and string value "2|B" for key for the second row, etc.

Comment: Oh god now.. why would you create strings for this? It adds a layer of nothingness. Say you create that string. Now every time you want the ID you have to decompose again.

Comment: user2540812
Yes.At first I achieve this like your answer! But faster...
Thanks for your answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that can give you an idea:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SO17416111
{
    class Class
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    // Note that definition of Class and Student only differ by name
    // I'm assuming that Student can/will be expanded latter. 
    // Otherwise it's possible to use a single class definition
    class Student
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            DataTable table = GetData();
            Dictionary<Class, List<Student>> d = new Dictionary<Class, List<Student>>();

            foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
            {                
                // If it's possible to get null data from the DB the appropriate null checks
                // should also be performed here
                // Also depending on actual data types in your DB the code should be adjusted as appropriate
                Class key = new Class {Id = (int) dr["ClassID"], Name = (string) dr["ClassName"]};
                Student value = new Student { Id = (int)dr["StudentID"], Name = (string)dr["StudentName"] };

                if (!d.ContainsKey(key))
                {
                    d.Add(key, new List<Student>());
                }
                d[key].Add(value);
            }
            foreach (var s in d.Keys)
            {
                foreach (var l in d[s])
                {
                    Console.Write(s.Id + "-" + s.Name + "-" + l.Id + "-" + l.Name + "\n");
                }
            }
        }

        // You don't need this just use your datatable whereever you obtain it from
        private static DataTable GetData()
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("ClassID", typeof (int));
            table.Columns.Add("ClassName", typeof (string));
            table.Columns.Add("StudentID", typeof (int));
            table.Columns.Add("StudentName", typeof (string));

            table.Rows.Add(1, "A", 1000, "student666");
            table.Rows.Add(2, "B", 1100, "student111");
            table.Rows.Add(5, "C", 1500, "student777");
            table.Rows.Add(1, "A", 1200, "student222");
            table.Rows.Add(2, "B", 1080, "student999");
            return table;
        }
    }
}
```

Note, that this can be compiled and tested as a console application - I substituted your `Response.Write` with `Console.Write`. I'm also generating a test DataTable, you should be able to use one that is already present in your application. As far as Class/Student classes go, you have several options here: you can have two separate classes as I show, you can use the same class or you can even use a [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536.aspx) class. I suggest you use two separate classes, as it improves readability and maintainability.

Note if you just need to output them, you don't need a dictionary or anything to that effect:

```
// Add null checks and type conversions as appropriate
foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
{
    Response.Write(dr["ClassID"] + "-" + dr["ClassName"] + "-" + dr["StudentID"] + "-" + dr["StudentName"] + "<br>");
}
```