# Compound key for dictionaries in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is great for doing fast lookups using the strongly-typed key; sometimes, however, I need to do lookups based on a unique combination of two (or more) variables. My "design pattern" for accomplishing this is to concatenate the values together using a separator, like this:

```
String compoundKey = productID.ToString + "~" + colorID.ToString;
myDict.Add(compoundKey, myObject);
```

This method seems a bit hacky. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3976265/397503) uses a `struct` but I'm not convinced that it is any better.

What is the preferable way of making dictionaries work with compound keys?

Comment: the value of the struct is that the keys parts are available without parsing the key.

Answer (score 11):

If your key is made up of two parts, the most obvious solution is a variable which has two parts. The "classical" way to produce this is a `struct`:

```
struct MyKey {
    public string PartA;
    public string PartB;
}
```

.NET will hash both fields for `Dictionary<MyKey, object>`. It's better to use a `struct`, not a `class`, because by default the identity of a `class` is defined by where the reference points (similar to the concept of pointers in C or C++) and not the values of the fields. You can, of course, `override` the `Object.GetHashCode` method in your `class` - but it's less work to just use a `struct`.

In practice, .NET already has a convenience for such situations: A `struct` with 2 fields can be represented as a `Tuple<string, string>`. You can then define:

```
var d = new Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, object>
```

And you will index with `d[new Tuple<string, string>("some value", "some other value")>]`.

This looks a bit bulky, so you can add `using MyKey = System.Tuple<string, string>` to the beginning of your `.cs` file. Then you will be able to index with `d[new MyKey("some value", "some other value")]`. The `using a = b` notation acts as a compile time search and replace.

Comment: I believe the `>` inside `d[new MyKey("some value", "some other value")>]` (in the final paragraph) should be removed - appears to be a cut-and-paste typo.

Comment: Note that if you make a struct for your pair, you should override GetHashCode or supply your own IEqualityComparer because the default GetHashCode for structs does *not* necessarily hash both fields! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926776/how-does-native-implementation-of-valuetype-gethashcode-work/5927853#5927853

Answer (score 8):

> What is the preferable way of making dictionaries working with compound keys?

My preferred method is to make a custom immutable class for the Key type.  This requires a bit of work, but is very clean and clear, and works for any combination of types.

You can also customize the `GetHashCode` and equality computations if required, as well.

---

If you're using `string` or types that properly implement hashing and equality, you can use a [`Tuple<T1,T2>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  If the values within your compound type are more complex, or you need custom equality/hashing (ie: only compare off an ID within an entity object instead of the all properties), a custom class allows you full control over how the equality and hashing are determined for your keys.

Comment: What about using `Tuple<T1,T2,...>`?

Comment: Just don't forget to make that class immutable.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Tuples work fine, too - they're just ugly when you go to work with the type, and may or may not implement hashing appropriately, depending on the data stored in the key.

Comment: @Reed: this is the sort of thing I was trying to elicit. Could you add that to your answer, along with a description of the kind of class which, "depending on the data stored in the key" "may not implement hashing correctly".

Comment: @ReedCopsey: and one sentence about immutability please.

Comment: @ReedCopsey: works great. I had already upvoted you, so take the thought as the deed: +2

Comment: @ReedCopsey: Can you share a code example? I'm particularly interested in seeing an example of a key comprised of a String and an Int.

Comment: @poke With a string and int, you could either use `Tuple<string,int>` or make a class like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3976305/65358